# What is &HA0000 constant in this code

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapi

```
Public Class Form1
  Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
    Get
      Dim CP As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
      CP.Style = &HA0000
      Return CP
    End Get
  End Property
End Class
```

I did a google search and found that &HA0000 is APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP. But this code is to minimize and restore a non-border form when click on taskbar icon. Please give me an explain. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are window styles. The list of which can be found over on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600.aspx).

Window styles are bit flags that are combined using bitwise OR. So, first decompose `000A0000` into its constituent parts: `00080000` and `00020000`. Now, `WS_SYSMENU` is `00080000` and  `WS_MINIMIZEBOX` is `00020000`.

Whoever wrote the code using magic constants should be given a suitably humiliating punishment. That code should read:

```
CP.Style = WS_SYSMENU Or WS_MINIMIZEBOX
```

Obviously you'll need to define the `WS_*` constants, but do take the time to do so for the benefit of future readers of the code.

Comment: I think `000A000 = 00080000 Or 00020000 = WS_SYSMENU Or WS_MINIMIZEBOX`. Anyway, I got the idea. Thanks

Comment: Do'h! Yes, your maths is better than mine!